# ¿Cómo ordenar el resultado de una consulta de acuerdo a la fecha mas próxima a la actual? - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

Tabla 1: reactivo_lotes

- codigo_lote PK
- codigo_entrega FK
- numero_lote
- presentacion
- almacenamiento
- ubicacion
- total_unidades
- marca
- fecha_vencimiento
- estado

Trato de obtener todos los registros de esa tabla de que acuerdo al registro que tenga la fecha de vencimiento mas próxima a la actual. Para ellos probé la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM reactivo_lotes WHERE estado = 1 ORDER BY fecha_vencimiento
```

Pero lo único que hace esto es ordenar los registros de acuerdo al orden que los inserte, ya probé agregando el `DESC` al final y obtengo el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizas calculando una columna con la diferencia de dias respecto a la fecha actual

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *, ABS(fecha_vencimiento - current_date) as ddif
          FROM reactivo_lotes rl
         WHERE estado = 1) t0
 ORDER BY ddif asc;
```

Comment: Marca error: ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «as»

Comment: Corregido el error. Había un error de sintaxis y una fuincion de fecha no definida. El código ya funciona